# Does pure javascript functions work in cheerios

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

Does functions like substring indexOf ,lastIndexOf,Substring etc work in cheerios ??

[Does these work in cheerio](https://jsfiddle.net/423Lynue/1/)

I want to know which all native javascript functions in cheerio

```
var s=$( "body" ).html();
var temp1=$(s);
alert(temp1.children().html());


alert(temp1.html());
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = s;
alert(temp.children[0].innerHTML);


s = s.substring(s.indexOf(">")+1,s.lastIndexOf("<")-1);
alert(s);
//document.querySelector(".Extracted").innerHTML=s;
$(".Extracted").html(s);
```

Comment: Q: What happened when you tried indexOf(), or tried substring()?  Q: Any particular reason standard functions *WOULDN'T* work? Q: Do you really want a list of *ALL* possible "native Javascript functions in Cheerio"???

Comment: I havent tried but I was confused that when some one asked about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all native functions work in cheerio

Comment: so you are telling me all these code would execute correctly in cheerio ?